# Is this file lock issue due to me copying the DB file for every MSTest test? (using DeploymentItem annotation)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, sqlite, mstest

**BACKGROUND**:

- I've running unit tests in VS2008 using MSTest.
- My project has a SqlLite database.
- I have found that I needed to arrange for the default database file to be copied to the MSTest area for the test to be able to find it.  I am using the following annotation about the test code to arrange this:
  [DeploymentItem("database.db3")]

**ISSUE**:

- When I run the "all tests" at once via VS2008 I get the below-mentioned error on one of the tests.  When I run this test alone it passes fine.
- The error I am getting is:
  "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: **The database file is locked database is locked**"
- Again, when I run the test that throughs this issue alone it works fine & passes

**QUESTION**:

Any ideas/suggestions regarding how to address this issue?  Is it due to the way I'm manually copying the database file for each test (i.e. each test I have one of the above-mentioned annotations)

*Example of full test:*

```
/// <summary>
///A test for process
///</summary>
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("database.db3")]
public void processTest()
{
    Coordinator target = new Coordinator();
    target.MyConfig.clear_database();

    target.process();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. I just create a sqlitedb in my unit test by opening a connection to a not existing file. However I can't delete this file in my teardown because it is locked.

Comment: Do u have to programmatically create the tables then?

Comment: Yes, the application creates the tables and so do the unit tests. My tests start with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the first unit test to run leaves the DB file open. Be sure to close the DB file.

Try using a [TestInitialize()] method in you test fixture to copy/create and then open the DB file while using a [TestCleanup()] method to close and then delete the DB file.

Comment: the problem is I couldn't work out how to manually copy the file, noting the directory changes each test run.  Hence I used the "[DeploymentItem("IntranetSync.db3")]" approach which seems to work. Is there a equivalent way to delete?   (i.e. noting I'm not really sure how to manually hook in a script that would do the deletion)

Answer (score 0):

Call static method SQLiteConnection.ClearAllPools() or SQLiteConnection.ClearPool() just before you want to delete the database file.